# Xamarin: Couldn't find "libmonodroid.so" emulator error

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I've been getting this problem for a couple days and haven't found a solution yet.

I've been using an `Android 7.0 ARM (armeabi-v7a)` image for my emulator. Because it's so painfully slow, I've been trying to use `Android 7.0 Intel Atom (x86_64)` with `HAXM` but I get the following error when opening the app.

> AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>    dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/SiteToolsMobile.
>   Droid-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/SiteToolsMobile.Droid-1/l
>   ib/x86_64, /data/app/SiteToolsMobile.Droid-1/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64
>   , /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libmonodroid.so"

The full logcat can be seen here-

> --------- beginning of system
>   10-26 10:30:39.317  1534  1545 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.a
>   ction.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=SiteToolsMo
>   bile.Droid/md5988fcde8450a201101ada904f480bb79.SplashActivity (has extras)} from
>    uid 10007 on display 0
>   --------- beginning of main
>   10-26 10:30:39.360  2778  2778 I art     : Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (alread
>   y on)
>   10-26 10:30:39.368  1534  1715 I ActivityManager: Start proc 2778:SiteToolsMobil
>   e.Droid/u0a56 for activity SiteToolsMobile.Droid/md5988fcde8450a201101ada904f480
>   bb79.SplashActivity
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   --------- beginning of crash
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime: Process: SiteToolsMobile.Droid,
>    PID: 2778
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>    dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/SiteToolsMobile.
>   Droid-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/SiteToolsMobile.Droid-1/l
>   ib/x86_64, /data/app/SiteToolsMobile.Droid-1/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64
>   , /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libmonodroid.so"
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Runtime.loa
>   dLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.System.load
>   Library(System.java:1076)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at mono.MonoPackageManag
>   er.LoadApplication(MonoPackageManager.java:34)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at mono.MonoRuntimeProvi
>   der.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:42)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityT
>   hread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityT
>   hread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityT
>   hread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityT
>   hread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityT
>   hread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.di
>   spatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loo
>   p(Looper.java:148)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityT
>   hread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Met
>   hod.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.
>   os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   10-26 10:30:39.395  2778  2778 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.
>   os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   10-26 10:30:39.396  1534  2013 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity Sit
>   eToolsMobile.Droid/md5988fcde8450a201101ada904f480bb79.SplashActivity
>   10-26 10:30:39.699  1534  2013 I WindowManager: Screenshot max retries 4 of Toke
>   n{e7ebe9 ActivityRecord{6e79c70 u0 SiteToolsMobile.Droid/md5988fcde8450a201101ad
>   a904f480bb79.SplashActivity t6 f}} appWin=Window{a134507 u0 Starting SiteToolsMo
>   bile.Droid} drawState=1
>   10-26 10:30:39.736  1534  2729 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   10-26 10:30:40.201  1534  1548 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for Act
>   ivityRecord{6e79c70 u0 SiteToolsMobile.Droid/md5988fcde8450a201101ada904f480bb79
>   .SplashActivity t6 f}
>   10-26 10:30:43.005  2778  2778 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 2778 SIG: 9
>   10-26 10:30:43.016  1534  2729 E Surface : getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buff
>   er: 0x7fb4b733ab20
>   10-26 10:30:43.027  1534  2013 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focus
>   ed, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Pr
>   oxy@67e1464 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@f656261
>   10-26 10:30:43.053  1534  1716 I ActivityManager: Process SiteToolsMobile.Droid
>   (pid 2778) has died
>   10-26 10:30:43.207  1534  1553 W AppOps  : Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1
>   000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0

So i know it can't find this lib, but I don't know why it can't find this lib and I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried uninstalling the app, cleaning the solution, and rebuilding.
I've tried the `6.0` as well as `7.1.1` system images.

I haven't tried reinstalling xamarin or anything else because that would take the rest of the day on the network I have available to me.

**Why doesn't `libmonodroid.so` exist and how do I fix it?**

**EDIT**

x86_64 is enabled. Here is a screenshot of my device and the advanced android options.

AVD Settings-

[image]

Build Options-

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!

Disable ever ABI except x86_64.

I don't know yet which ABI causes the conflict. I think maybe X86. Because he always deployed a MonoRuntime...

Comment: I should have commented on this earlier. I found that disabling every abi except the one you intend to use works. Maybe checking "Generate one page (apk) per selected API" would also work.

Comment: This is not correct solution, this disables debugging app in physical device

Comment: This is the only thing that has worked for me too, fresh install Win10, Xamarin 4.2.0.719.

Comment: Removing everything will disable debugging on devices.

Comment: Thanks for giving the direction! In my case, it's activating all of them instead to make it works.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the `x86_64` ABI in your Android Build Advance options:

[image]

Comment: Updated my original post with screenshots. `x86_64` is checked.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson You can always sift through the generated `.apk` to ensure this setting is being respected in the respective `lib/<ABI>` folders.

Comment: I also recommend using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app to see this directly on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Removing everything except `x86` and `x86_x64` will disable debugging on physical device.

The correct solution is to remove `arm64-v8a` and it will work alright.

Answer (score 0):

Recently installed Xamarin and ran into the same issue, found the error in the Android Device Log (Visual Studio: Tools/Android/Device Log...) and this solution did resolve the issue. I went one step further and narrowed down the issue (at least in my case) to the need to remove supported architecture: armeabi. None of the other supported architectures caused the issue. I'm running Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.2.2.11, with Android 7.1.1 under the Android Emulator using Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64) and Google's Nexus 5 device.

Answer (score 0):

On, Visual Studio for Mac (8.7.1) this issue came up recently and there is an installation package for the Xamarin.Android SDK has been given in the GitHub issue.

Please check: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4983

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/11/11.0#august-18-2020--xamarinandroid-11020), it started happening again and is fixed in the latest update of Visual Studio. So just check for updates and then install them.