# armeba-v7a couldn't find libmonodroid.so

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, apk

I'm having a problem running on some devices in the GooglePlay Pre-launch report. The error from the devices like the LG G6 running Android 7.0 is couldn't find libmonodroid.so. The issue isn't purely related to Android 7.0, I have 6.0, 7.1, 8.0 and 5.1 devices all failing with the same error.

I renamed the apk, opened it with WinZip and the libmonodroid.so is definitely in the apk file. I'm building the app using multiple abi files, currently I'm building armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 and I have unchecked x86_64 based on other peoples posts. I also tried unchecking the arm64-v8a and it made no difference.

[image]

I know other people must have had this problem in the past.

I followed James Montemagno's recommendation of submitting the multiple abi files because submitting just one apk it exceeds the 100Meg limit.

Does someone have a solution?

I can provide as much information as needed. I tried the suggestions in a previous post and none solved the problem, again I'm not just attempting to run on a single device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin: Couldn't find "libmonodroid.so" emulator error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266537/xamarin-couldnt-find-libmonodroid-so-emulator-error)

Comment: I tried their suggestions and none seemed to work. It isn't an option to just build 1 version because I'm uploading to GooglePlay for release.

Comment: @AlanAnderson The LG G6's Snapdragon is `ARMv8-A`, so 64-bit and thus would work with  `armeabi-v7a` or `arm64-v8a`. Which ABI/APK is being installed in device (the 32bit or 64bit)?

Comment: Apparently the issue was including the armeabi.apk in GooglePlay, once I removed the old armebi (ARMv5TE) the problem went away. Now I'm just building armebi-v7a and arm64_v8a with the x86 and all seems to be fine. I guess the libmonodroid.so wasn't compatible with the ARMv5TE image.